# Displaying block of text

Tags: powershell

I've done a bit of Googling and can't seem to find an effective method of displaying an entire block of text to the console. I would rather not use the `Write-Host` command on every line if I need to display a block of code. I'm trying to make an interactive script that's somewhat aesthetic. Is there  an example that someone could give me?

Comment: You can write multiple lines at once with `Write-Host`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a block of text you are having to use `write-host` on multiple times to show up the way you want?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

PowerShell supports multiline strings, either as [here-strings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx):

```
Write-Host @"
Some text you
want to span
multiple lines.
"@
```

or regular strings:

```
Write-Host "Some text you
want to span
multiple lines."
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I don't know why I couldn't find something online that was clean and clear. The other examples I'd found were 4 - 5 lines of code just to accomplish this. I knew it couldn't be that hard!

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Ansgar's examples, `Write-Host` accepts an array too.

```
'one','two','three' | Write-Host
```

So whether your multi-line string is a single string, or an array of lines, it will still work as expected with a single `Write-Host` call:

```
Get-Content mycode.txt | Write-Host
Get-Content mycode.txt -Raw | Write-Host
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '''multiline
text
here''' > filename.txt
```

Works as well